# How "Apache will serve any file mapped from an URL" Directory directive?

Tags: apache, configuration

I have a question about the Apache's Directory directive, here is what they say in the docs (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#directory):

> Note that the default access for <Directory "/"> is to permit all access. This means that Apache httpd will serve any file mapped from an URL. It is recommended that you change this with a block such as
>
> ```
> <Directory "/">
>   Require all denied
> </Directory>
> ```

But how will Apache do what they say (serve any file mapped from an URL) if I have only `DocumentRoot` set up, e.g.:

```
DocumentRoot "/usr/local/apache/htdocs"
```

No `Alias "/some/webspace/path" "/"`, `UserDir` or other URL mapping rules which map to the root `/` directory of the system?

In another section of the docs (Security Tips http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/misc/security_tips.html#protectserverfiles), they make a half-full example of UserDir as I can guess:

> One aspect of Apache which is occasionally misunderstood is the
>   feature of default access. That is, unless you take steps to change
>   it, if the server can find its way to a file through normal URL
>   mapping rules, it can serve it to clients.
>
> For instance, consider the following example:
>
> ```
> # cd /; ln -s / public_html
> Accessing http://localhost/~root/
> ```
>
> This would allow clients to walk through the entire filesystem. To work around this, add the following block to your server's configuration:
>
> ```
> <Directory "/">
>     Require all denied 
> </Directory>
> ```
>
> This will forbid default access to filesystem locations.

Is what they say about the `Directory` directive at `http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#directory` just a warning in the case you use modules like `mod_userdir` like they then show at `http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/misc/security_tips.html#protectserverfiles`? Or is there something else, maybe a little detail about `Directory` not given in the doc?

Thanks for the attention!

Answer (score 0):

In Apache, there are unlimited hypothetical plugins/directives that could change **only** how a URL is mapped to the filesystem. Obvious/mainstream ones are DocumentRoot, Alias, AliasMatch, RewriteRule, UserDir etc.  But there's no telling what other ones might exist.

Apache simply separates the URI to filesystem mapping completely from whether the core is willing to actually serve from that filesystem location.

There are a few ways you can accidentally expose things, like with mod_rewrite, and the default configuration file protects you from this with the defaults on <Directory />. The manual is not good at always emphasizing the differences in the compiled-in defaults and the contents of the default conf.  The latter can change when repackaged which is tricky.

Comment: But does this mean that in my example, even if I do not deny `<Directory />`, if I disable overriding with `.htaccess` inside the `DocumentRoot`, access to the `/` root will still be impossible cause Apache won't map to the `/` root?